# How to sign a message using Baclpack?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, wallet, javascript, typescript

I want to sign an arbitrary data (eg. a string message) with Backpack and receive the signature as a result. How can I do it with backpack?

Answer (score 3):

Hey looking at the code it should be
`signMessage(tx: Buffer, address: string): Promise<string>;`

so `const signature = await window.xnft.solana.signMessage(tx);`

Comment: Thank you (+1). What package do you use for that? With backpack installed to my browser, I get undefined when I try to access `window.xnft`.

Comment: Hey, i would recommend use https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/ with https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter. This will support all wallets including backpack. You can create a ready to use dapp using npx create-solana-dapp "Yourappname"